# Alamofire 5 showing error after installing it with Carthage, "'Alamofire has no member named request"

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, carthage

I've installed Alamofire 5 using Carthage, and it keeps showing error that it has no member request.

```
   Alamofire.request(route).responseJSONDecodable { response in }
```

> **Module 'Alamofire' has no member named 'request'**

Comment: Hi. Can you jump to the code of Alamofire using command + ctrl?

Comment: I did that and I can see request func there! @Vyacheslav

Comment: Quick suggestion: If your current level can't find how to do it (nothing wrong about that), I'd strongly recommend to use an official release, not a beta one until they give a Migration guide.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are using Alamofire 5 then you should use `AF.request` instead of `Alamofire.request`.
Check out usage example [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md).